# Typescript shortcut when mapping over a collection into a constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor

Coming from Java we can transform a collection by calling its constructor like

```
collection.stream().map(Repsonse::new).collect(.....);
```

Is there a way to do it in TypeScript?

```
 return response.data.jobAllocationRules.map(ruleResponse => {
        return new Rule(service, ruleResponse);
 });
```

Is there a similar shortcut? I tried the following and it didn't work.

```
return response.data.jobAllocationRules.map(Rule::new);
```

Comment: You're describing a *method reference*; no, TS doesn't have that. See e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2769 and the various linked issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest is:

```
return response.data.jobAllocationRules.map(ruleResponse => new Rule(service, ruleResponse));
```

In arrow functions, you can omit the block `{...}` with just an expression, and that expression becomes the resurn value of the function